# Find top deciles from dataframe by group

Tags: r, dataframe, rank, quantile, split-apply-combine

I am attempting to create new variables using a function and `lapply` rather than working right in the data with loops. I used to use Stata and would have solved this problem with a method similar to that discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5024437/how-to-rewrite-this-stata-code-in-r/).

Since naming variables programmatically is so difficult or at least awkward in R (and it seems you can't use indexing with `assign`), I have left the naming process until after the `lapply`. I am then using a `for` loop to do the renaming prior to merging and again for the merging. Are there more efficient ways of doing this? How would I replace the loops? Should I be doing some sort of reshaping?

```
#Reproducible data
data <- data.frame("custID" = c(1:10, 1:20),
    "v1" = rep(c("A", "B"), c(10,20)), 
    "v2" = c(30:21, 20:19, 1:3, 20:6), stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

#Function to analyze customer distribution for each category (v1)
pf <- function(cat, df) {

        df <- df[df$v1 == cat,]
        df <- df[order(-df$v2),]

    #Divide the customers into top percents
    nr <- nrow(df)
    p10 <- round(nr * .10, 0)
    cat("Number of people in the Top 10% :", p10, "\n")
    p20 <- round(nr * .20, 0)
    p11_20 <- p20-p10
    cat("Number of people in the 11-20% :", p11_20, "\n")

    #Keep only those customers in the top groups
    df <- df[1:p20,]

    #Create a variable to identify the percent group the customer is in
    top_pct <- integer(length = p10 + p11_20)

    #Identify those in each group
    top_pct[1:p10] <- 10
    top_pct[(p10+1):p20] <- 20

    #Add this variable to the data frame
    df$top_pct <- top_pct

    #Keep only custID and the new variable
    df <- subset(df, select = c(custID, top_pct))

    return(df)

}


##Run the customer distribution function
v1Levels <- levels(data$v1)
res <- lapply(v1Levels, pf, df = data)

#Explore the results
summary(res)

    #      Length Class      Mode
    # [1,] 2      data.frame list
    # [2,] 2      data.frame list

print(res)

    # [[1]]
    #   custID top_pct
    # 1      1      10
    # 2      2      20
    # 
    # [[2]]
    #    custID top_pct
    # 11      1      10
    # 16      6      10
    # 12      2      20
    # 17      7      20



##Merge the two data frames but with top_pct as a different variable for each category

#Change the new variable name
for(i in 1:length(res)) {
    names(res[[i]])[2] <- paste0(v1Levels[i], "_top_pct")
}

#Merge the results
res_m <- res[[1]]
for(i in 2:length(res)) {
    res_m <- merge(res_m, res[[i]], by = "custID", all = TRUE)
}

print(res_m)

    #   custID A_top_pct B_top_pct
    # 1      1        10        10
    # 2      2        20        20
    # 3      6        NA        10
    # 4      7        NA        20
```

Comment: You can get rid of most of this with `quantile()` and `hist(breaks = define_your_nonuniform_breaks...)`

Comment: Don't call your df `data` because that shadows a builtin.

Comment: When you do `df <- df[df$v1 == cat,]` for each categorical level, you are just doing a kludgy Split-Apply-Combine. See documentation on plyr/dplyr group_by. Try to read about R paradigms for doing common operations.

Comment: I retitled this *"Find top-10% and 10-20% decile entries from dataframe, grouped by v1"* since that's the intent of the code. You might like to rephrase the question.

Comment: @smci Looks like "dataframes" is not the right tag for R "data.frame"s

Comment: The new title probably better reflects the discussion that played out. Is it too specific? How about "Find top deciles in a dataframe by group"? or "grouped by a variable"?

Comment: Yeah, I think those titles sound better; no need for "v1" or specific mention of percents. Btw, adding thanks or calling out another question (as you've done at the top of your question) is not looked favorably upon, as it distracts from the content of the Q&A. If you want to link it, you should probably just do so in a comment here. A reference: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260776/1191259

Comment: Separate post related to this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29987611/merging-data-frames-in-a-list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idiomatic way to do this kind of thing in R would be to use a combination of `split` and `lapply`. You're halfway there with your use of `lapply`; you just need to use `split` as well.

```
lapply(split(data, data$v1), function(df) {
    cutoff <- quantile(df$v2, c(0.8, 0.9))
    top_pct <- ifelse(df$v2 > cutoff[2], 10, ifelse(df$v2 > cutoff[1], 20, NA))
    na.omit(data.frame(id=df$custID, top_pct))
})
```

Finding quantiles is done with `quantile`.

Comment: Please see my [new post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29987611/merging-data-frames-in-a-list) regarding how to combine these results. Anything you would add?

Answer (score 7):

Stick to your Stata instincts and use a single data set:

```
require(data.table)
DT <- data.table(data)

DT[,r:=rank(v2)/.N,by=v1]
```

You can see the result by typing `DT`.

---

From here, you can group the within-`v1` rank, `r`, if you want to. Following Stata idioms...

```
DT[,g:={
  x = rep(0,.N)
  x[r>.8] = 20
  x[r>.9] = 10
  x
}]
```

This is like `gen` and then two `replace ... if` statements. Again, you can see the result with `DT`.

---

Finally, you can subset with

```
DT[g>0]
```

which gives

```
   custID v1 v2     r  g
1:      1  A 30 1.000 10
2:      2  A 29 0.900 20
3:      1  B 20 0.975 10
4:      2  B 19 0.875 20
5:      6  B 20 0.975 10
6:      7  B 19 0.875 20
```

These steps can also be chained together:

```
DT[,r:=rank(v2)/.N,by=v1][,g:={x = rep(0,.N);x[r>.8] = 20;x[r>.9] = 10;x}][g>0]
```

---

(Thanks to @ExperimenteR:)

To rearrange for the desired output in the OP, with values of `v1` in columns, use `dcast`:

```
dcast(
  DT[,r:=rank(v2)/.N,by=v1][,g:={x = rep(0,.N);x[r>.8] = 20;x[r>.9] = 10;x}][g>0], 
  custID~v1)
```

Currently, `dcast` requires the latest version of `data.table`, available (I think) from Github.

Comment: `dcast(DT[,r:=rank(v2)/.N,by=v1][,g:={x = rep(0,.N);x[r>.8] = 20;x[r>.9] = 10;x}][g>0], custID~v1)` to put the columns side-by-side.

Comment: @ExperimenteR Cool, thanks! I haven't learned/installed `dcast` yet.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need the function `pf` to achieve what you want. Try `dplyr/tidyr` combo

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>% 
    group_by(v1) %>% 
    arrange(desc(v2))%>%
    mutate(n=n()) %>% 
    filter(row_number() <= round(n * .2)) %>% 
    mutate(top_pct= ifelse(row_number()<=round(n* .1), 10, 20)) %>%
    select(custID, top_pct) %>% 
    spread(v1,  top_pct)
#  custID  A  B
#1      1 10 10
#2      2 20 20
#3      6 NA 10
#4      7 NA 20
```

Comment: This is great, you beat me to it. @KevinM, read up the paradigms for these dplyr commands. (data.table is also a possible package, but much less friendly to an R beginner. So learn with dplyr.)

Comment: Apologies for strongly worded. Toned down as suggested.