# Merge data frames within a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list which looks like,

```
lapply(sample_list, head, 3)

$`2016-04-24 00:00:00.tcp`
   ports freq
8    443  296
12    80  170
5     23   92

$`2016-04-24 00:00:00.udp`
  ports freq
4   161  138
7    53   45
1   123   28

$`2016-04-24 01:00:00.tcp`
   ports freq
13   443  342
20    80  215
10    25   60

$`2016-04-24 01:00:00.udp`
   ports freq
4    161   85
8     53   42
12   902   27
```

I want to merge the data frames that come from the same protocol (i.e. the `tcp` together and `udp` together)
So the final result would be a new list with 2 data frames; One for `tcp` and one for `udp` such that,

```
lapply(final_list, head, 3)

$tcp
  ports freq.00:00:00 freq.01:00:00
1   443           296           342
2    80           170           215
3    23            92            51

$udp
  ports freq.00:00:00 freq.01:00:00
1   161           138            85
2    53            45            42
3   123            28            19
```

**DATA**

```
dput(sample_list)
structure(list(`2016-04-24 00:00:00.tcp` = structure(list(ports = c("443", 
"80", "23", "21", "22", "25", "445", "110", "389", "135", "465", 
"514", "91", "995", "84", "902"), freq = structure(c(296L, 170L, 
92L, 18L, 16L, 15L, 14L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Dim = 16L)), .Names = c("ports", 
"freq"), row.names = c(8L, 12L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 9L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 
10L, 11L, 15L, 16L, 13L, 14L), class = "data.frame"), `2016-04-24 00:00:00.udp` = structure(list(
    ports = c("161", "53", "123", "902", "137", "514", "138", 
    "623", "69", "88", "500"), freq = structure(c(138L, 45L, 
    28L, 26L, 24L, 24L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 1L), .Dim = 11L)), .Names = c("ports", 
"freq"), row.names = c(4L, 7L, 1L, 11L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
5L), class = "data.frame"), `2016-04-24 01:00:00.tcp` = structure(list(
    ports = c("443", "80", "25", "23", "88", "21", "161", "22", 
    "445", "135", "389", "993", "548", "110", "143", "502", "514", 
    "81", "995", "102", "111", "311", "444", "789", "902", "91"
    ), freq = structure(c(342L, 215L, 60L, 51L, 42L, 32L, 31L, 
    18L, 18L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Dim = 26L)), .Names = c("ports", "freq"
), row.names = c(13L, 20L, 10L, 9L, 22L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 15L, 4L, 
12L, 25L, 18L, 2L, 5L, 16L, 17L, 21L, 26L, 1L, 3L, 11L, 14L, 
19L, 23L, 24L), class = "data.frame"), `2016-04-24 01:00:00.udp` = structure(list(
    ports = c("161", "53", "902", "514", "123", "137", "69", 
    "138", "389", "443", "88", "623"), freq = structure(c(85L, 
    42L, 27L, 24L, 19L, 15L, 15L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Dim = 12L)), .Names = c("ports", 
"freq"), row.names = c(4L, 8L, 12L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 10L, 3L, 5L, 
6L, 11L, 9L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("2016-04-24 00:00:00.tcp", 
"2016-04-24 00:00:00.udp", "2016-04-24 01:00:00.tcp", "2016-04-24 01:00:00.udp"
))
```

Bonus question: What is the structure of `freq`? I never saw `int [1:16(1d)]` before.

```
str(sample_list$`2016-04-24 00:00:00.tcp`)
'data.frame':   16 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ ports: chr  "443" "80" "23" "21" ...
 $ freq : int [1:16(1d)] 296 170 92 18 16 15 14 4 3 2 ...
```

The code I used to create the list (In this case called `try1`)

```
protocol_list <- lapply(per_hour1, function(i) split(i, i$protocol))
Analytic_Protocol_List <- lapply(protocol_list, function(i) lapply(i, dest.ports))
try1 <- lapply(unlist(Analytic_Protocol_List, recursive = FALSE), `[[`, 1)
```

Note that solutions from [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29987611/merging-data-frames-in-a-list) do not work for this case. Maybe because of the structure?

Comment: Regarding bonus question, how did you create *sample_list* object?

Comment: Your "freq", probably, is a result from a call to `table` which, always, produces results having "dim" attribute (probably, with some attributes lost along the way) -- `str(unname(unclass(table(sample(5, 50, TRUE)))))`. Otherwise, a 'length == 1' "dim" attribute must have been set somewhere

Comment: @alexis_laz would this structure restrict me on certain operations?

Comment: @Sotos : E.g. on mathematical operations, it might give "non-conformable" errors -- `a = 1:6; b = matrix(1, 2, 3); da = structure(a, dim = 6); a + b; da + b`. I guess other operations that handle "dim" attributes or do not accept ones might be problematic, too. To remove all but "names" attributes, you could use `c` (`c(da) + b`).

Comment: Great. Thank you @alexis_laz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another alternative:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data.table::melt(sample_list) %>%
  separate(L1, into = c("time", "protocol"), sep = "\\.") %>%
  unite(f, variable, time) %>%
  spread(f, value) %>%
  split(.$protocol)
```

Which, using your data, gives:

```
$tcp
   ports protocol freq_2016-04-24 00:00:00 freq_2016-04-24 01:00:00
1    102      tcp                       NA                        1
2    110      tcp                        4                        2
3    111      tcp                       NA                        1
5    135      tcp                        2                        6
8    143      tcp                       NA                        2
9    161      tcp                       NA                       31
11    21      tcp                       18                       32
12    22      tcp                       16                       18
13    23      tcp                       92                       51
14    25      tcp                       15                       60
15   311      tcp                       NA                        1
16   389      tcp                        3                        5
18   443      tcp                      296                      342
20   444      tcp                       NA                        1
21   445      tcp                       14                       18
22   465      tcp                        2                       NA
24   502      tcp                       NA                        2
25   514      tcp                        2                        2
28   548      tcp                       NA                        3
31   789      tcp                       NA                        1
32    80      tcp                      170                      215
33    81      tcp                       NA                        2
34    84      tcp                        1                       NA
35    88      tcp                       NA                       42
37   902      tcp                        1                        1
39    91      tcp                        2                        1
40   993      tcp                       NA                        4
41   995      tcp                        2                        2

$udp
   ports protocol freq_2016-04-24 00:00:00 freq_2016-04-24 01:00:00
4    123      udp                       28                       19
6    137      udp                       24                       15
7    138      udp                        6                        4
10   161      udp                      138                       85
17   389      udp                       NA                        2
19   443      udp                       NA                        2
23   500      udp                        1                       NA
26   514      udp                       24                       24
27    53      udp                       45                       42
29   623      udp                        6                        1
30    69      udp                        5                       15
36    88      udp                        4                        2
38   902      udp                       26                       27
```

---

**Update**:

If you want to sort by `freq`, you could do:

```
data.table::melt(sample_list) %>%
  separate(L1, into = c("time", "protocol"), sep = "\\.") %>%
  unite(f, variable, time) %>%
  spread(f, value) %>%
  arrange(protocol, desc(`freq_2016-04-24 00:00:00`)) %>%
  split(.$protocol)
```

Comment: great! We can also include `arrange` and sort them easily. Thank You

Comment: I am actually struggling to `arrange` :) Can you include it in your answer? :)

Comment: @Sotos You want to sort by `ports` ? Maybe you are struggling because in your initial input `ports` is a `character`. See update.

Comment: Not by ports. I am trying to sort (decreasing) by frequency. I added `lapply(new_list, function(i){i[order(i[,3], decreasing = TRUE),]})` to get it...`new_list` being the resulting list from your script

Comment: ahh... I almost had it. Forgot the backtics

Answer (score 2):

For the `rbind`ing you can try the following:

```
do.call(rbind, sample_list[grep("tcp", names(sample_list))])
```

and:

```
do.call(rbind, sample_list[grep("udp", names(sample_list))])
```

and as refined by Marat below:

```
d <- do.call(rbind, sample_list)
d2 <- data.frame(d,do.call(rbind,strsplit(rownames((d)),'[.]')))
lapply(split(d2,d2$X2),dcast,ports~X1,value.var='freq')
```

Comment: @VincentBonhomme, maybe something like `d <- do.call(rbind, sample_list); d2 <- data.frame(d,do.call(rbind,strsplit(rownames((d)),'[.]'))); lapply(split(d2,d2$X2),dcast,ports~X1,value.var='freq')`

Comment: amazing. would you like to post it as an anser or do I edit the question?

Comment: @MaratTalipov : well we have a smarter option above anyway ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you can just merge by ID
create a ID for each row of the data frame
let lappy(X) = x

```
  x$1 <- cbind(ID=1:nrow(x$1))
```

same for x1,x2,x3....,xN

```
  newx <- merge(x$1,x$2,...,x$N, by=ID)
```

since id merging is used overlapping won't occur, jusıt there each list$(X) as a data frame itself